# LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

The header TCP.h

```
class CTCPcomm {
public:
    CTCPcomm(bool bOverLapped = false, long lTimeOut = 0);
    ~CTCPcomm(void);
```

The class TCP.cpp

```
CTCPcomm::CTCPcomm ( bool bOverLapped, long lTimeout ) {
.......
}
CTCPcomm::~CTCPcomm ( void ) {
.......
}
```

This is being called for plc_test.cpp

```
int main(){
CTCPcomm    m_TCPcon(true, lTimeout);
.......
}
```

this gives me error,

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CTCPcomm::CTCPcomm(bool,long)" (??0CTCPcomm@@QAE@_NJ@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'm_TCPcon''(void)" (?? __Em_TCPcon@@YAXXZ) plc_test
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CTCPcomm::~CTCPcomm(void)" (??1CTCPcomm@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic atexit destructor for 'm_TCPcon''(void)" (??__Fm_TCPcon@@YAXXZ) plc_test
```

Im using Visual Studio 2015, and compiling it as .exe file.
I have read many posts aready, but they say to change the execution type to .lib
But i want this project to be a executable file, so i want to stick with .exe
Why does it compile with no error if compiled as .lib and not in .exe?
What should be done if i want to execulte it as .exe with no error?

Comment: Is TCP.cpp actually in your project?

Comment: yes. It is a part of my project

Answer (score 0):

I put the code above on a Visual Studio 2015 project and it works fine (compiling as exe) both in x86 and x64.

What else are you doing? Other then what you showed you only need:
 `#include "TCPcomm.h"` //after #include "stdafx.h"
and
    `long lTimeout = 10;` //in main